# ctrl-] is not working for tcl code navigation

Tags: tags, tcl, vim, ctags

I am new to Tcl/Tk, I am using Vim to code and browsing. The syntax highlighting for Tcl/Tk is working fine. The jump into the function using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>]</kbd> doesnt work it gives me an message saying that "`cstag: tag not found`". I have installed ctags and generated tags using "`ctags -R *.tcl`". I have extensively used namespaces in Tcl/Tk code. The tags generated in tags file is something like this "`namespace1::function1`".

How do i get <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>]</kbd> (and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>T</kbd> for popping from stack) working in Vim?

The function to jump could be in either of the 2 formats shown below

1. `function1`
2. `namespace1::function1`

Comment: Beware that `ctags -R *.tcl` would generate `tags` only for the files in the current directory, that unless your subdirs also have extension `.tcl`. Try `ctags -R .` instead.

Answer (score 3):

Found a work around for my problem:

The tags file that generated contained tags in the format `namespace::function`.

I just removed `namespace::` from generated tags file. 
Now <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>]</kbd> works!!!

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
:set isk+=:
```

Seems like ":" doesn't get recognized as a codeword by default.

To make this work every time, add the line to your '~/.vimrc'.

Source: http://vim.1045645.n5.nabble.com/How-to-have-vim-recognize-in-cursor-for-tcl-namespaces-tp1163540p1163541.html

Comment: That's actually the proper answer to the question. Why has it got down voted?

Answer (score 2):

Vim said he can't find the tags you generated.

Add `set tags=./tags,tags;` in your `.vimrc` and try again.

Comment: xdazz, thanks for your reply but its not working...I am guessing that the map for ctrl-] is not getting set properly meaning if it gets set to namespace1::function1 then it should work. However I am able to navigate to that function by using :ta namespace1::function1...

Comment: Are you opening Vim from the same directory that contains the tags file? If you generated the tags file in the Tcl/Tk directory but started Vim in your home directory or something, it won't read it unless you set the tags parameter as shown in this answer, but adding the Tcl/Tk directory to the list.

Comment: @Derek: I am opening Vim from the same director which contains the tags file.

Answer (score 1):

Your .vimrc should have the following line

```
set tags=tags;/
```

Paste it, save, restart vim and you're golden.

Answer (score 0):

What keyboard layout are you using? I'm not familiar with your particular problem, but I've had problems with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>]</kbd> on a Swedish keyboard when navigating the help pages.

There, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>]</kbd> doesn't work for me (probably since <kbd>]</kbd> is typed with <kbd>Altgr</kbd>+<kbd>9</kbd>). However, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+ 'key to the left of Enter' works (which is where <kbd>]</kbd> is located on an English keyboard layout).

I can add that for my problem with the help pages I first tried to map <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>]</kbd> to another combination, but this still didn't work (not sure why). So if you are having the same problem, remapping might not solve the problem.