# ctags is not directing to the methods for namespaces in tcl

Tags: vim, namespaces, tcl, ctags

```
namespace eval core {
 set b {}
}

proc core::edit_core {} {
}

proc test {} {
set x 34
}

test

edit_core
```

When pressing CTRL + ] on test , then directing to definition,
while on edit_core ,it is not finding the cstags.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ctrl-\] is not working for tcl code navigation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11078605/ctrl-is-not-working-for-tcl-code-navigation)

Comment: What does your `ctags` command line look like? If you look in the `tags` file, what does the `edit_core` line contain?

Comment: @PeterLewerin core::edit_core

Comment: @PeterLewerin On executing this "ctags --list-kinds " , only for tcl "namespace" option is not there..So I think there should be some command to enable it for namspace also.                                                                       I tried this "ctags -R --Tcl-kinds=+p --fields=+iaS --extra=+q --language-force=Tcl", but its not working

Comment: @ayushigupta: I don't have my configuration file with me, will look when I get home.

Comment: @PeterLewerin Sure :)

Comment: @ayushigupta: I can't find the files. I seem to have offloaded them to an external drive or something. I'll have a look again tomorrow, but it could take a while to find them. Sorry!

Comment: I implement new tcl parser that supports namespace. https://github.com/universal-ctags/ctags/pull/1354 .

Answer (score 1):

The latest Universal-ctags(https://ctags.io) can handle namespaces.

```
[jet@localhost]~/var/ctags% cat foo.tcl
cat foo.tcl
namespace eval core {
 set b {}
}

proc core::edit_core {} {
}

proc test {} {
set x 34
}

test

edit_core

[jet@localhost]~/var/ctags% ./ctags -o - --fields=+K foo.tcl
./ctags -o - --fields=+K foo.tcl
core    foo.tcl /^namespace eval core {$/;" namespace
edit_core   foo.tcl /^proc core::edit_core {} {$/;" procedure   namespace:core::edit_core
test    foo.tcl /^proc test {} {$/;"    procedure
[jet@localhost]~/var/ctags% ./ctags -o - --fields=+K --extras=+q foo.tcl
./ctags -o - --fields=+K --extras=+q foo.tcl
core    foo.tcl /^namespace eval core {$/;" namespace
core::edit_core::edit_core  foo.tcl /^proc core::edit_core {} {$/;" procedure
edit_core   foo.tcl /^proc core::edit_core {} {$/;" procedure   namespace:core::edit_core
test    foo.tcl /^proc test {} {$/;"    procedure

[jet@localhost]~/var/ctags% ./ctags --list-kinds=Tcl
./ctags --list-kinds=Tcl
p  procedures
n  namespaces
[jet@localhost]~/var/ctags% ./ctags --list-kinds=ITcl
./ctags --list-kinds=ITcl
c  classes
m  methods
```